# What is the avqmd.plist and the _avqmd record in Users/Groups

Tags: macos, user-account

Today, I was trying to fix the file permissions and ownership on an external hard drive and while I was trying to add myself as a user/owner the through the get Info window, the system presented me with an unknown to me user with the name: _avqmd.

Of course there is no indication for such user in the system preferences -> users.

But I was also able to spot a avqmd.plist file inside: /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users

Does anyone know what is this and from where it comes from?

Comment: What version of OS X? Can you dump the plist to inspect it? If it's binary, use `plutil -convert xml1 -o - /path/to/user.plist` You can then see if it has a shell, proper information added. Normally all the _ users as OS related, but it would be a cool place to hide a malicious account if you were to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_avqmd` is an account created by the [Avira anti-virus](http://www.avira.com/fr/free-antivirus-mac).

This account is used to run background tasks without the use of the overall priviliged account `root`. This is a correct security practice: separation of priviledge.

If you want to see what this account is used for, run for example:

```
ps -l -u _avqmd
```

If you didn't install `Avira`, then this account is a problem. For example, it might be a crapware trying to hide under the name of this software.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I remember me installing Avira at some point - but moments later I uninstalled it. So this seems to be leftovers. I also found late last night after googling, some references pertaining to the avqmd term relating to avira. [**Apple Discussions**](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6514692?start=0&tstart=0), and [**Avira Help**](http://mac-help.avira.com/en/avira_mac_security/pages/uninstall.htm)

Comment: Apparently the uninstall process didn't finished its job. This is a common problem, and another good question.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get some more details on the user by querying your directory database rather than looking at the record files on the filesystem:

```
dscl . -read /Users/_avqmd
```

Hopefully you'll find enough threads to pull on. It's not an account on any of the first few Macs I checked, but perhaps someone else has tracked it down already and has a more concrete answer.

Comment: thanks bmike - I m still searching on it... but yet to find something on the web.